# CakePHP strange memory exhausted on save()

Tags: php, cakephp

## Brief Explanation

I'm working locally on XAMP. CakePHP version: 2.6.3.

I've a model named `Brand`. A brand has an `id`, a `name` and an `enabled` field.

There're many permission levels on this project, let's just take two: *Admin* and *Superadmin*.

- Admin: Can do CRUD everywhere. Can't see deleted elements
- Superadmin: Can do CRUD everywhere. Can see deleted elements

In this project ***nothing gets deleted for real***, this is why the `enabled` field exists.

## My Code Logic

Cake provides fast methods to `save()` or `delete()` records so I decided to create a convenient method that I can use in any model to *disable* elements and to `restore` elements. I've called them `disable` and *restore* and I've put them in my `AppController.php`

```
protected function disable($id)
{
    return $this->{$this->modelClass}->save(array('id' => $id, 'enabled' => 0));
}


protected function restore($id)
{
    return $this->{$this->modelClass}->save(array('id' => $id, 'enabled' => 1));
}
```

My objective was to use these methods in any model I'll create in the future for convenience.

## How I use these methods

The following code is the `delete` action of `BrandController`

```
public function delete( $brand_id )
{
    if( $this->disable($brand_id) )
    {
        $this->flash('Brand deleted successfully', DS . $this->Session->read('locale') . DS . 'brand' . DS . 'index', 2);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->flash('An error occured', DS . $this->Session->read('locale') . DS . 'brand' . DS . 'index', 2);
    }
}
```

An here is `restore` action of `BrandController`

```
public function restore( $brand_id )
{
    if( $this->restore($brand_id) )
    {
        $this->flash('Brand restored successfully', DS . $this->Session->read('locale') . DS . 'brand' . DS . 'index', 2);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->flash('An error occured.', DS . $this->Session->read('locale') . DS . 'brand' . DS . 'index', 2);
    }
}
```

## My Problem

If I use `if ($this->disable($brand_id)) ...` no problems, If I use `if ($this->restore($brand_id)) ...` I get infinite loading and this Error

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php on line 803
```

BUT... the funny thing is that I replace `if ($this->restore($brand_id))` with the code inside `restore` method ( becoming `if ($this->Brand->save(array('id' => $brand_id, 'enabled' => 1)))` *I get no error AT ALL*

Why it does this? Those two methods are just identical.

I don't want to set `memory_limit` to `-1` ***is not a solution at all.***

Comment: You are creating an infinite loop that's all. You are calling `$this->restore()` inside the restore method, and it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've snipped the code unrelated to your problem:

```
public function restore( $brand_id )
{
    $this->restore($brand_id);
}
```

The `BrandController` restore method is calling itself. You need to change this to call the appropriate restore method.

Comment: Newbie error. Sometimes we just need another person to watch our code. Thanks

Comment: @KevinCittadini No problem. Glad to help.